# How to integrate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^3}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How would one go about integrating such the function $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^3}$$

The reason I am struggling with this is because normally i would use a contour ingrgration around a semi circle and then extend the radius up to infinity and minus infinity and then solve using cauchys integral theorem.

However, this function is odd and so i am wondering how one would go about integrating such a function since it would disappear over such limits.

Comment: You could instead use partial fractions to factor the difference of cubed terms.

Comment: The question is from a worksheet concerning complex analysis, so would be intereseted to see if there is way that uses contour integrals that I just have not noticed.

Comment: @TymaGaidash would that work in this case?  It might turn into an $\infty - \infty$ situation then.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor That is why we have improper integration with splitting the integral and using limits

Comment: It has been solved by the other question. Thanks for your input really apprecaiate it!

Comment: @TymaGaidash Okay, I follow you now, thanks.  Got a finite answer.